# KVO nsmutablearray remove object notification

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

i have a singleton class with a `nsmutablearray`

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"Received notification: keyPath:%@ ofObject:%@ change:%@",
          keyPath, object, change);

    //[super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];

}
//array accessors
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)object
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"heldJoins"];
    [heldJoins addObject:object];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"heldJoins"];
}
- (void)removeObject:(id)object
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"heldJoins"];
    [heldJoins removeObject:object];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"heldJoins"];
}
```

i "observe" the changes made to this array from another class
my rootviewcontroller

```
    [CCV addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"heldJoins" options:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey||NSKeyValueChangeNewKey context:NULL];

}    
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
    {    
        NSLog(@"Received notification: keyPath:%@ ofObject:%@ change:%@",keyPath, object, [change allKeys]);
    }
```

this works and i am notified when there is an object removed or added
however i cannot figure out (and maybe its not possible) how to see the object that was removed or added  (mainly need the object when its removed not added though)

i know the `NSDictionary` variable `Change` should have my object but all it has is one key "kind" which always equals 1 since there is always 1 change made to the array.

the `nsmutablearray` is filled with numbers 500,100,300
so when one of those numbers is removed i would like to know which number was removed in my observer class
how can i do that?

answer code:

```
[CCV addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"heldJoins" options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld ||NSKeyValueChangeNewKey context:NULL];

NSLog(@"Received notification: keyPath:%@ ofObject:%@ change:%@",keyPath, object, [change valueForKey:@"new"]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you didn't specify NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld when you added the observer.

Comment: Your addObserver call is using the wrong constants for options.  For example you are using NSKeyValueChangeOldKey but the correct constant is (as I said in my answer) NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld.

Comment: Also you are using `||` but you should be using `|`.

Comment: u certainly seem to know but i get syntax errors when using the single line vs double

Comment: Your error from the single | is because you used the wrong constants.  You used constants of type NSString*.  The correct constants are type NSUInteger.